# windows get IP dynamically

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, ip

i want to implement the following logic. Does it possible to have such implementation using batch or power shell ? please share with me script for that.

Let say I have a configuration file with the following "config.propertis":

```
BOOTPRORO=statis or dhcp
IPADDR=192.168.10.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.10.1
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

I want that at startup the system will check that file and configure network accordingly:

1. OS: Windows
2. if in BOOTPROTO=dhcp, when use DHCP in network configuration and ignore all another in config file, except DNS
3. if in BOOTPROTO=static, then use all variables from config file to configure IP as static.

So, I have such logic under the Linus, using shell. The script in configured in rc.d and execute before network service. Does it possible to implement such over the Windows ? Guys, please share the script !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can definitely do this.

First things first, because a lot of systems have more than one network interface, you'll need to determine what the ifIndex is of the adapter that we want to change.  Do that by running `Get-NetIPInterface`.  You should see results like this:

[image]

In my example and going forward, I'll be using this index, 41.  **You should change this to match what you find on your own computer**.

OK, now to read from the text file. Since you've provided the data in a key=value pair format, commonly called a hashtable, we can easily grab the data from there using ConvertFrom-Stringdata.  This will give us a PowerShell hashtable, and we can pull the needed line out like this.

```
$values = get-content T:\config.properties | ConvertFrom-StringData
$values.BootProro
>statis
```

We can us this to set the PC in Dynamic IP mode, or to set static addresses.  Now, for you to use this in your environment, you need to find the ifIndex, as I mentioned before.  replace my index of 41 with your own, and then give it a shot.  I've added -WhatIf to every line, so you will see *what would happen* when you run it.  If you're happy with the changes it woudl make, remove -Whatif to make the script actually change the settings.

```
$values = gc T:\config.properties | ConvertFrom-StringData
if ($values.BOOTPRORO -eq "dhcp"){
  Write-Output "---DHCP mode detected in 'config.properties' file"
  Write-Output "---Setting Set-NetAdapter -DHCP Enabled"
  Set-NetIPInterface –InterfaceIndex 41 –Dhcp Enabled -WhatIf
  }
else{
  Write-outPut "---static mode detected in 'config.properties' file"
  Write-Output "---Removing network configuration"
  Remove-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex 41 -whatif

  Write-Output "---Setting new network configuration equal to"
  $values

  New-NetIPAddress -DefaultGateway $values.GATEWAY -IPAddress $values.IPADDR -PrefixLength 24 -InterfaceIndex 41 -WhatIf
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ServerAddresses $values.DNS -InterfaceIndex 41 -WhatIf
 }
```

The output looks like this:[image]

Comment: Thanks 1RedOne. I guess is what I need. After having the script done where I need put it in order to have it executed at windows startup?

Comment: Use the Windows Task Scheduler and create a new Basic Task that runs when you Power on the system.  Run the program "powershell.exe" with the parameter "-file C:\PathTo\ThisPS1.ps1" and you should be good to go.  

Here are two methods you could create a scheduled task, if you find the 'Task Scheduler' program to be difficult:

http://superuser.com/questions/688007/how-can-a-powershell-script-be-automatically-run-on-startup

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj130675.aspx

Comment: which is powershell command to get ifIndex from Get-NetIPInterface to a variable to use that in above script ?

Answer (score 1):

in Windows we can set ip address via batch file or powershell script but when you use dhcp address your ip is Dynamic not static I Imposition you want static ip address 
BAtch-file

```
netsh interface ip set address name=”Local Area Connection” static 192.168.10.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1
netsh interface ip set dns name=”Local Area Connection” static 8.8.8.8
```

if you want be dhcp You should set

```
netsh interface ip set address name=”Local Area Connection” source=dhcp
```

note I Imposition you nic name is Local Area Connection

In powershell V3.0 and Later we Used

```
New-NetIPAddress –InterfaceAlias “Local Area Connection ” –IPv4Address “192.168.10.10” –PrefixLength 24 -DefaultGateway 192.168.10.1
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias “Local Area Connection” -ServerAddresses 8.8.8.8
```

and for startup you can put script .bat and .ps1 in startup windows but attention you should `Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass` before U run any script of powershell
for startup any script see [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/138159/how-to-enable-programs-and-custom-scripts-to-run-at-boot/)

Comment: yes, right DHCP - is dynamic, what I need when BOOTPROTO is static when use static IP for Windows, otherwise configure as dynamic

Comment: if i understand your needs corectly ,You can use loop in your script change ip every n minute if you want but dynamic ip for server's service to global is not right

Comment: so as you proposed if I'll create a batch script with "netsh" and put it in startup folder that will be good, right ?

Comment: @DumitruGutu it's depend on what you need for example if you need change ip every 10 minute from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.1 you can use `for /l %v in (1,1,10) do netsh interface ip set address name=”Local Area Connection” static 192.168.1.%v 255.255.255.0 192.168.10.1` you use task scheduler run script every 10 min if you want